# "Звони-пиши" - нужен ли тут дефис?

Tags: дефис

Нужен ли тут дефис? Если нужен, то в каких случаях?

Comment: О том, какое правило тут действует, см. [Особые случаи употребления дефиса: дочки-матери, печки-лавочки, внуки-правнуки](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447966/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Жили-были старик со старухой...*
*Пиши-звони* - в электронной переписке друзей, почему нет? Дефис придает некий оттенок непрерывности, чтобы адресат не пропадал надолго из поля зрения. Глаголы однотипные, означают связь собеседников друг с другом.

> А. И. Солженицын. Бодался теленок с дубом (1967-1974)  Идешь-бредёшь, спотыкаешься в колонне по пять, руки назад, думаешь: только и ждут там услышать нас.

Пишите дефис!
Есть похожее выражение : *пиши-читай*, а вот это (пиши-звони) относительно новое, из электронной эры.

> Ф. И. Буслаев. О народной поэзии в древнерусской литературе (1859)  Бросились на силу все витязи: Стали они силу **колоть-рубить**…

А можно и вот эдак :
*Люблю-целую-обнимаю, скоро приеду, вышлите денег, всем привет!*
А вот такось : *звони-люби!*

> Б. А. Садовской. Пшеница и плевелы (1936-1941) // «Новый Мир», 1993  Ястребок на ветке **сидит-качается**, перышки носом перебирает, в глаза тебе смотрит.

Comment: @Дерзкий, я полностью с Вами согласна. Тоже удивляюсь косности остальных отвечающих.

Answer (score 7):

Через дефис пишутся прилагательные и наречия, образованные повторением слов, основ или повторением синонимичных слов: белый-белый снег, мало-мальски, подобру-поздорову и т.д. В приведенных примерах с глаголами тоже налицо повторение синонимичных слов (жили-были, колоть-рубить,идешь-бредешь). И даже в "пиши-читай" есть оттенок синонимичности (пиши и читай написанное). В связке же "пиши, звони" нет никакой синомичности, здесь лишь призыв совершать последовательные или разделенные действия, поэтому нужна запятая.

Дорогой Ярик!Извините, что так фамильярно к Вам обращаюсь, но у меня один из внуков-двойняшек - Ярик (правда, Ярослав), поэтому Ваше имя меня греет. Вообще, если бы Вы выбрали имя не "Дерзкий", а "Яростный" или "Ярый", то это больще соотносилось бы и с Вашим подлинным именем, и с особенностями натуры, которая яростно (яро?) отстаивает свою точку зрения. Мне очень импонирует Ваша страстная убежденность в том, что Ваше мнение верное. Это замечательное качество, которым я не вполне обладаю, поэтому меня в чем-то легко переубедить. Ваши доводы заслуживают уважения и внимания, но они не полностью убеждают меня. Если говорить конкретно о приведенных Вами примерах, то в "петь-плясать" и в "ткать-вышивать" можно уловить если не абсолютную синонимичность, то, по крайней мере,тесную связь. "Петь-плясать"= веселиться, "ткать-вышивать"= рукодельничать. А вот в "пишите, звоните" никакой такой связки не наблюдается. Более того, ряд можно продолжить: пишите, звоните, приходите, телеграфируйте, посылайте СМС, поддерживайте связь, отправляйте радиограммы.... Кстати, в старых советских газетах была такая рубрика: "Пишите, звоните, заходите". Слишком длинный комментарий, наверное, не пройдет. Но последнее - о "боитесь ступить без формальной подсказки справочника". Я справочники давно изучал, не все запомнил и не все принял. Сейчас почти не заглядываю в них, а пользуюсь наработанным опытом, основанным на прежней базе знаний по орфографии и пунктуации, которые стараюсь трансформировать для современных речевых ситуаций.

Comment: А смартфон причем?

Comment: Пиши-звони - это со смартфона действия производятся нынче, я так полагаю. Современная связь.

Comment: А в вопросе нет ничего про смартфон. Это Вы придумали.. Поэтому  Вам и минус.

Comment: Поясните, Виктор, почему в действиях "пиши, звони" Вы не видите никакой *синонимичности*, коль скоро оба глагола обозначают всего лишь различные виды связи между разделенными расстоянием людьми? Вы понимаете шаткость своего "запрета" или специально не хотите понимать специфику современного общения **при посредстве** современных видов связи. Отвечайте, с удовольствием почитаю Ваши аргументы!  
*Мы во все инстанции **писали-звонили**, никто нам даже не ответил...*
 Так можно написать или НЕТ??? Или Вы шаг боитесь ступить без формальной подсказки справочника.

Comment: Составители правил опираются на корпус прошлых сочинений, они полностью зависят от литературных прецедентов и не решаются внести что-то свое. Свободный автор не связан какими-либо запретами и умолчаниями, он творит по своему личному усмотрению.  
*Пишите-звоните, буду рад живому общению...*  
>Василий Белов. Плотницкие рассказы (1968) Все у нее выходило само собой, неизвестно, когда **петь-плясать** научилась, когда **ткать-вышивать**, плести кружева.

Петь и плясать, ткать и вышивать - НЕ СИНОНИМЫ!  
Вы поняли свою ошибку, Виктор? Надеюсь, что уже поняли, Вы вдумчивый пользователь форума.

Comment: Специально для "Дерзкий".Мой ответ на Ваши вопросы находится в дополнении к тому ответу, который я дал вначале

Comment: Виктор! Вы дали абсолютно неубедительный ответ по поводу "синонимичности". *Петь-плясать* = веселиться, это естественно так, ну а *пиши-звони* = свяжись со мной, дай о себе знать, не пропадай надолго, сообщай новости, контактируй... Вам достаточно или мне продолжить?  
Воистину : кто не хочет слышать, не услышит вовек.  
Как справедливо отмечено @yupaz, форум закрыл свои глаза, уши, рот и мозги. Печальный факт. Хватило ума только на **пошлый нажим "тревожной" кнопки**. Мои вам соболезнования, прощаюсь со всеми до тех пор, пока не вернут мой полный рейтинг, то есть навсегда. Честь имею!

Comment: Ярик, спасибо за отклик. Мне действительно интересно то, что Вы пишете в защиту своей позиции. Но почему Вы считаете, что я должен с Вами соглашаться обязательно? Я думаю, что Ваша точка зрения имеет право на существование, она интересна, и это Ваше право отстаивать ее. А мое право - соглашаться или не соглашаться с ней. Мне кажется, обиды здесь ни при чем.Напрасно Вы собираетесь уйти с сайта. Вас читать интересно, хотя Вы не всегда сдержанны. Сколько Вам все-таки лет? Мне кажется, Вы молодой, горячий парубок. ТАк ведь?

Answer (score 6):

Не вижу оснований для дефиса. Вряд ли это сложное слово. Скорее однородные сказуемые, нужно поставить запятую. Разве что в какой - нибудь записи с целью передать особенности устной речи,  и то  сомнительно.