# Особые случаи употребления дефиса: дочки-матери, печки-лавочки, внуки-правнуки

Tags: грамотная-речь, дефис

Дочки-матери, печки-лавочки, внуки-правнуки — есть ли название и объяснение подобным случаям употребления дефиса?

> В магазин, в доктора, в ту же школу, в **дочки-матери**, в войну… [Анна Фенько. Невроз по поведению // «Коммерсантъ-Власть», 2002]
>
> Я вон пошёл с удочкой, посидел на бережку в тенёчке ― и всё, и **печки-лавочки**. [Василий Шукшин. Печки-лавочки (1970-1972)]
>
> Будут плыть в небе радуги,
> Будет мир, будут праздники,
> И шагнут **внуки-правнуки**
> Дальше нас.
> (Роберт Рождественский)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Видимо, этот случай подпадает под такое правило (дефисное написание, п. 7):

> http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/part-009.htm
>
> Через дефис
> пишутся сложные наименования, образованные путем соединения
> синонимичных (*однородных* по значению) или антонимичных
> (противоположных по значению) слов: *грусть-тоска, друзья-приятели,
> правда-истина, сила-удаль; вопросы-ответы, купля-продажа,
> приемка-выдача.*

Печки с лавочками можно условно отнести к "однородной" (не обязательно одинаковой) бытовой утвари.

Comment: Можно сказать, что дочки-матери антонимичны, а внуки-правнуки синонимичны?

Comment: В рамках условностей этого правила, наверное, можно. Хотя у Гоголя "пригорки, ручейки" (такой вариант попался) через запятую (цитируют это иногда и через дефис). Возможно, имеет значение устойчивость сочетания (у Чичикова это вышло спонтанно).

Answer (score 3):

Вообще говоря, при выборе формы написания желательно говорить  **не только  о правилах письма, но и о грамматике тоже,** учитывая, что правила соответствуют грамматике.

**Дефисное написание  является промежуточной формой** между слитным написанием слов и раздельным написанием словосочетаний. Через дефис могут писаться **как слова, так и словосочетания.**

В Грамматике-80 такие слова называют **составными наименованиями** (их относят **к словосочетаниям**).

Следует различать **три группы** сложных слов (словосочетаний) с дефисным написанием.

1) **Составное наименование (сочинительная связь, обе части склоняются)**: диван-кровать, вагон-ресторан, платье-костюм, ковер-самолет

Также: Из Грамматики-80

http://rusgram.narod.ru/1814-1829.html#1820

Примечание. К приложению не относятся соединения двух слов, называющие сложносоставный предмет и по своему строению, функциям, а иногда и по сочетаемости приближающиеся к слову: хлеб-соль, пух-перо, разгрузка-погрузка, чашки-ложки, банки-склянки, чашки-блюдца (посуда), отец-мать, папы-мамы (шутл.) (родители), руки-ноги (конечности), гуси-утки (птица), гуси-лебеди, дружки-приятели. Аналогично в глаголах: кормил-поил, холила-нежила, просил-умолял; в наречиях: туда-сюда, тихо-мирно, чинно-благородно.

Такие существительные могут взаимоопределяться, варьируя и 
 интенсифицируя значения дуг друга: буря-непогода, тоска-кручина, шум-гром, ночка-ноченька и др.

2) **Сложное слово (сочинительная или подчинительная связь,** **первая часть не склоняется**): плащ-палатка, царь-колокол, шеф-повар.

3) **Приложение + определяемое существительное** (подчинительная связь, обе части склоняются): утес-великан, мороз-трескун, шапка-невидимка, ветер-суховей.

Таким образом, эти группы определяются с учетом **склоняемости** первой части и **сочинительных или подчинительных** отношений между частями.

Comment: В этом источнике примеры, близкие к _теме вопроса_, приведены (в числе прочих) только в примечании к п. 1, причём исключительно для пояснения, что они "к приложению _не относятся_". Не уверен, что напр. "гуси-утки" - пример "сложносоставного предмета", хотя подвести все сгрупированные там примеры под единое определение затруднительно.

Comment: @Alex_ander  Гуси-утки? Хотела найти предложение с этим "предметом", но нашлась только гибридная порода "утка-гусь", которую иначе называют мулард, Но ведь что-то  это составное наименование обозначает!  Что касается "этого источника", то это наша родная Грамматика-80, другого-то нет, все сведения оттуда.  А вот подвести все примеры под единое определение - это значит классифицировать их по какой-то системе. Нельзя  употребление дефиса изучать только по орфографическим справочникам (но это я так думаю, большинство считает иначе).

Comment: Гугловский поиск, естественно, будет натыкаться на банальное перечисление. Я добавил слово "всякие (гуси-утки)" и нашёл в книжке (А. Бондаренко, Выбор - побег, 2017) предложение: "Да и всякие гуси-утки отсутствуют..." Грамматика - грамматикой, а правописание держится на регламентированных _условностях_ передачи заведомо грамотной речи. :)

Comment: Прекрасно, гуси-утки найдены, вот они: "А рыба не плещется, ни единого «рыбьего» круга не наблюдается. Да и всякие гуси-утки отсутствуют, что, согласись, весьма странно – от их КРЫЛАТОЙ БРАТИИ в здешних местах отбоя нет, на Сизых болотах полощутся почти в каждой луже".  Итак, гуси-утки - это собирательное наименование водоплавающих птиц, то есть вполне конкретный сложносоставный предмет. Но не приложение и не сложное слово. Получается, что правописание всё-таки держится на грамматике.

Comment: Конкретная форма здесь присутствует во множественном числе, к которому не подходит определение "сложносоставный предмет", а собирательное наименование (водоплавающие и т. п.) - абстракция.

Comment: А грамматика вообще наука абстрактная, она изучает языковые формы и вполне может отвлечься от мн. числа. Чашки-блюдца - это посуда, а в нашем  случае гуси-лебеди - это живность всякая. Это все мелкие детали с точки зрения грамматики.

Comment: С грамматической точки зрения мне кажется более подходящим другое обобщение: объединение пары разнородных слов дефисом происходит на основе исключения соединительного союза между ними ("гуси да утки" или "гуси с утками", "печки с лавочками", "пригорки да ручейки").

Comment: Ну да, это то, что называется сочинительной связью при отсутствии союзов,  когда слова, с одной стороны, уже тесно связаны между собой и образуют единое понятие, а с другой - еще достаточно свободны и самостоятельны. Такое промежуточное состояние обозначается дефисом. (Кстати, ему соответствует произношение без паузы).