# Сложные слова, состоящие из антонимов: как они пишутся и какой смысл несут?

Tags: глаголы, наречия, сложные-слова, дефис-тире, антонимы

В одной книге в Интернете увидел такое слово: "далеко-близко". Кажется, это было про лётчика (что-то вроде: "Далеко-близко летает"). Но что это за конструкция такая, когда антонимы объединены в одно слово? Наверное, тогда существуют и "глубоко-мелко", "коротко-длинно" (есть же "вверх-вниз", правильно?). Напоминает действие: от одного к другому (скажем, "далеко-близко летает" = "летает и далеко, и близко"; "глубоко-мелко ныряет" = "ныряет и глубоко, и мелко").

А как быть с глаголами такого же вида, они тоже пишутся через дефис или уже через тире? "Люблю-ненавижу", "стою-брожу"? Однако ведь есть "хочу — не хочу" (а не "хочу-не-хочу"), "понимаю — не понимаю" (а не "понимаю-не-понимаю"), то есть с глаголами порой пишется тире в значении "потом", "как следствие"...

Есть какое-то правило, литературные примеры подобных сложных слов, состоящих из антонимов?

**ДОПОЛНЕНО**

"Грамма.ру" считает, что нужен дефис ("люблю-ненавижу"), а при наличии отрицательной частицы ставится тире (например, видимо, "хочу — не хочу").

*Сочетания соотносительных или близких по значению слов пишутся через дефис: ходит-бродит, есть-пить, любить-ненавидеть и т. д.
Иным является случай с конструкцией, в которой есть отрицательная частица. По синтаксическим признакам это конструкция с отдельными, противопоставленными словами, и при написании следует использовать тире.*

Answer (score 1):

**Интересный вопрос**, который наши участники незаслуженно обошли вниманием (нет ответов, один голос появился только недавно, я же сейчас проголосую за него).

Это **нестандартный вопрос**, хотя тема рассматривается во многих источниках (они будут указаны в приложении), в том числе он обсуждался и на нашем форуме.
Однако во всех случаях не хватает **общего взгляда** на проблему написания указанных слов (слитно, раздельно, дефис, запятая, нет знаков). Поэтому можно обозначить **несколько тем**, по которым пользователь должен составить решение, отчасти принятое **им самим.**

**1. Ассоциативные связи**

**Ассоциация** (лат. Associatio — соединение, взаимосвязь), в психологии и философии — закономерно возникающая связь между отдельными событиями, фактами, предметами или явлениями. [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ассоциация_(психология)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Об ассоциативных связях говорится во всех источниках (в правилах и в грамматике), но **антонимы** указаны только в Грамма.ру. Именно этот вопрос обсуждался на форуме.

Мне представляется важным не конкретные случаи (синонимы, антонимы  и др.), а **наличие единого понятия**, существующего в сознании и требующего обозначения (хорошо, если можно подобрать обобщающий синоним).

Ассоциативные связи **между глаголами** также возможны, но они встречаются реже, чем для существительных.

**2. Тире и дефис: как сделать выбор**

Если ассоциативная связь имеет место, то пишется дефис, в противном случае используется тире. Дефис пишется при повторе слов для выражения эмоций и экспрессии.  Наиболее частотные слова с дефисным написанием указаны в словарях (еле-еле, отец-мать).

**3. Как влияют приставки, предлоги, частицы на форму письма.**

При повторе слов могут использоваться приставки и суффиксы (крест-накрест, давным-давно). Но вот дефисное написание союзов и частиц допускается только **в терминологии** (название растений: не-тронь-меня, мать-и-мачеха), в других же случаях дефис не пишется.

Это указано в ПАС: § 155. В конструкциях с повторами между двумя частями **не ставится** никакого знака, если хотя бы одна из частей содержит **пробел.**  Например: страшно не страшно, а...; ждёт не дождётся. Ср. написание повторов без НЕ: сидят-сидят, глядят-глядят, ждут-пождут.

**4.  Когда мы ставим запятую и когда вообще нет знака**

Интересно то, что варианты с дефисом и тире можно заменить использованием запятой при наличии перечислительной интонации, в противном случае возможно отсутствие знаков.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

В тоже время при выборе формы письма для сочетаний, которых нет в орфографическом словаре, нужно дополнительно учитывать **фонетические** особенности конкретных слов, а также **традицию** их употребления. Соответственно, желательно ориентироваться на практику письма (в Нацкорпусе, например).

Вообще говоря, выбор **дефисного (или слитного) написания** — это более ответственное решение, так как речь идет о лесике слов. Поэтому здесь особенно важно ориентироваться **на предыдущие примеры** (в словаре, в текстах художественных произведений, а также в правилах), и в случае сомнений **выбор тире** (а не дефиса) более предпочтителен.

**ВЫВОД**

Таким образом, на ваши вопросы вы должны ответить сами, определив по тексту наличие или отсутствие ассоциативных связей, а также придерживаясь указанных в ответе рекомендаций. Поэтому при решении нужно рассматривать **конкретные предложения.** Если они у вас есть, то можно обсудить.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447966/Особые-случаи-употребления-дефиса-дочки-матери-печки-лавочки-внуки-правнуки](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447966/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8)

http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=68#pp68 § 53

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=64#pp64  § 118, §155

http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.46

Грамматика-80  (§ 1820, приложение) http://rusgram.narod.ru/1814-1829.html#1815

**Нацкорпус:**

(1) ― Не хочу, ― ответила бабушка. ― Кто тебя спрашивает ― **хочу, не хочу**. Вставай. [Маша Трауб. Плохая мать (2010)]

(2) Опять же дрожание есть и в Пушкине, только иного сорта, когда он то близок к вам, будто хлопает по плечу, то тут же далёк, как звёзды, и потому мерцает… Но это не то мерцание, в нём нет мучительной болезненности, которую я преследую и которая происходит не из спаренности **близко–далеко**, но воля–стереотип… [А. Ю. Суконик. Вариация на тему // «Волга», 1999]

(3) Пословицы русского народа по теме **«далеко – близко»**
https://nsportal.ru/nachalnaya-shkola/osnovy-bezopasnosti-zhiznedeyatelnosti/2020/12/13/2-zanyatie-po-pdd-blizko-daleko

Comment: В одной песне есть превосходная строка, построенная на антонимах. Там парень летит в самолёте на встречу с девушкой, и вот строка: "Как же так медленно можно лететь так быстро?" Немного не в тему вопроса, просто вспомнилось *по ассоциации*.

Comment: В тему, конечно, если говорить об ассоциациях, а ведь именно это очень важно решить в каждом случае. А рядом их никак нельзя поставить, сложно что-нибудь придумать?

Comment: можно, но зачем ломать строку)

Comment: Эту мы ломать не будем (она же действительно превосходная), просто захотелось придумать такой вариант (так детям хочется узнать, что внутри игрушки). Но у меня  не получается...

Comment: Ага, если с наречиями так можно (дефисом соединять антонимы, и даже примеры есть), то как всё же быть с глаголами? Ну, например, если жена говорит, что "наши отношения находятся в плоскости люблю(, /-/ — )ненавижу"? Предположим, она имеет в виду, что тут значение не следствия или последовательности (утром провожаю на работу, люблю, а вечером ненавижу — когда пьяный приходит), а одновременности (когда ругаю его, одновременно и люблю, и ненавижу)... Чисто теоретически на основе правил тут допустим дефис?

Comment: Я бы поставила тире, это скорее не ассоциация, а обозначение антонимов, с помощью которых описываются отношения.  В Нацкорпусе приводится похожий пример ("не из спаренности близко–далеко"), и там стоит тире. Надо еще проверять вариант интонацией: при дефисе фактически слитное произношение слов с одним основным ударением, а здесь скорее два ударения. С другой стороны, авторский вариант с дефисом тоже возможен, но он будет вызывать вопросы.